# How to insert a newline before a range of specific formatted text in Microsft Word?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, wildcard

I scanned a dictionary in color with two columns and OCR'd it with Abby, which gave pretty good results. Now sometimes a newline is not recognised well enough, so I need to insert a newline before every colored text (I know the RGB color).

I convert my scanned images to word (abby strips all headers, pagenumbers,..) and now I want on every line "**phrase**:*description*". **Phrase** is in a blue color.

Using the find and replace tool, I search for **(<*>)** with format -> font -> textcolor = RGB(xx,xx,xx).  I replace this with **^p \1**, and this works great when **phrase** is a single word.

However, sometimes (most of the times), my phrase consists of multiple words, and I would only like one *newline* per **phrase**.

Is it possible to search for a range in a specific formatting (blue in my example), and add a *newline* in front of it using the find-and-replacetool or do I need a VBA-macro or is this not possible at all?

Thank you,

Wout

Comment: Yes, this is possible in VBA. Dunno if it's possible via search/replace, but I'm pretty sure, that it is not.

Comment: Apprently it is possible without VBA: [Link](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,481633,00.asp)

Comment: Hi @Rémi, changing the color can be done word by word, but if I follow those steps, I add a 'newline'-character before every word of my (multiword) **phrase**, instead of just before the first.

Comment: I think you'll have to use VBA for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference,

I solved my problem by first replacing all **word** with **###word**, and then replacing **word ###** with **word**. This way I only have **###** in front of words that have no *blue* textcolor before them.
After that I replaced **###** with **^p** (for some reason you can't use **^p** together with wildcards..).

Not very clean and probably nicer in VBA, but it ain't stupid if it works.

Thank you for your input!